# Did I raise too many flags too quickly?

Tags: discussion, support, flags

After <strike>single-handedly burning down</strike> reviewing stuff in [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) and [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) for a while, I decided to check out the flags I have raised so far and found out that I raised **six flags in one hour**:

[image]

Six flags in one hour is equivalent to raising a flag every 10 minutes. Is this something I should refrain from doing in order to reduce the pressure on moderators and high-rep users?

*Important note: This is NOT a request to give my flags more importance than others' flags.*

Comment: A flag every 10 minutes isn't much. As long as you have flags you can use them! If you don't try to flag every 5 seconds you should be fine.

Comment: A flag every 10 minutes only becomes a problem when all or most of your flags turn out to be inappropriate, which is rare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it a little funny how concerned you are `:)`. I've flagged a lot more without issue, although it gets a little more impractical once you reach 3k+ rep, since you can't flag for closure any more.

Some things require attention, so you have two options: flag or wait and hope another person flags. It's not going to fix itself, most likely.

For closure flags, assuming you are using them appropriately, the worst that would happen is some age away. (Which is common considering how full the close votes queue is, but at least you can follow up by viewing your flag history.)

I have flagged a lot of things within short time spans:

```
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:44   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:32   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:32   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:30   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:29   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:27   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:24   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:23   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:23   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:22   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:20   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:19   helpful
not an answer – Laurel Jun 8 at 2:17   helpful
```

(The list goes on...)